# Generate HTML Table that has Rows and Columns as Models in django with normal time complexity

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I would like to populate a table in a template, but I noticed that its extremely slow and i think that I am doing something terribly wrong (to be specific ... it take 3 seconds to handle one request from my localhost). I think that the whole reason of it being so slow is because of I am generating it over and over again ... which in my opinion is very bad thing to do ... sadly, I would like it to be pulled from DB in case of any problems (like server restart etc.) so thats why i do not want to initialise it as a global var and work with it that way.

***models.py***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)


class Note(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)


class Whistle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

***views.py***

```
class ProductTableView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "whistles_shop/table.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['whistle'] = Whistle.objects.all()
        context['note'] = Note.objects.all()
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        all_rows = []
        for cat in Category.objects.all():
            one_row = [cat.name]
            for note in Note.objects.all():
                whist = Whistle.objects.filter(category=cat, note=note)
                if whist:
                    one_row.append("X")
                else:
                    one_row.append("-")
            all_rows.append(one_row)
        context['tab'] = all_rows
        return context
```

***template.html***

```
     <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                {% for obj in note %}
                        <th>{{obj.name}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for row in tab %}
            <tr>
            {% for x in row %}
                <th> {{x}} </th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the speed would be awesome <3. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thx for the downvotes that were acctually unspecified... anyways ... for ppl that are wondering, I managed to male it go faster with putting the query calls outside of the forloop (by swaping database filter for lambda filters. If anyone has still even better approach, I will gladly welcome them ^^ Also, I am thinking about putting all the data to frontend and let the JS handle it, but i feel like thats just an overkilling :/ so we will see